# Verbs for the word achievements e.g other achievements he ... are (fill ... in)

Tags: verbs, confusable

Does this make sense?

> Other achievements he **attained**...

Or is it "obtained"?

Thank you everyone! This is my first time using this website and you have been very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you must use the noun "achievement" (rather than the verb "achieve") and find yourself in need of a verb to go with it, there are possibilities but all of them sound a little bit awkward.

*Perform*, *win*, *score* or *gain* are the sorts of things I have in mind.

e.g. ***He performed the remarkable achievement of three birdies in a row***.

But it would be less wordy to say ***He achieved three birdies in a row***.

As someone has noted ***achieve*** and ***achievement*** are already strong words.

Of course ***achievement*** works well with the verb *to be*, as in ***To have climbed Everest is a stunning achievement***.

Comment: You could also use the possessive - "His other achievements include..."